# Issue loading data from array into a select list in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have the following class:

```
class App extends Component {

  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {value: 'currentlyReading'};

    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
  }

  bookOptions = [{
        value: 'currentlyReading',
        text: 'Currently Reading'
    },
    {
        value: 'wantToRead',
        text: 'Want to Read'
    },
    {
        value: 'read',
        text: 'Read'
    },
    {
        value: 'none',
        text: 'None'
    }]

    onHandleChange = (e) => {
        this.setState({
            state: e.target.value
        })
    };

  handleChange(e){
    this.setState({value: e.target.value});
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <select value={this.state.value} onChange={this.handleChange}>
        {
          this.bookOptions.map((c) => {
            <option value={c.value} >{c.text}</option>
          })
        }
      </select>
    );
  }
}
```

If I render the select list with regular html syntax then it works perfectly, where as if I try to create it dynamically then it doesn't load anything. How would you go about creating a list dynamically in react so that it maintains its binding?

Any advice would be appreciated!

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you are using the curly braces in the following piece of code:

```
this.bookOptions.map((c) => {
  <option value={c.value} >{c.text}</option>
})
```

You are not returning anything, hence you are rendering an array of undefined elements. Remove that and your code should work as expected. See the working code below.

```js
class App extends React.Component {

  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {value: 'currentlyReading'};

    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
  }

  bookOptions = [{
        value: 'currentlyReading',
        text: 'Currently Reading'
    },
    {
        value: 'wantToRead',
        text: 'Want to Read'
    },
    {
        value: 'read',
        text: 'Read'
    },
    {
        value: 'none',
        text: 'None'
    }]

    onHandleChange = (e) => {
        this.setState({
            state: e.target.value
        })
    };

  handleChange(e){
    this.setState({value: e.target.value});
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <select value={this.state.value} onChange={this.handleChange}>
        {
          this.bookOptions.map((c) => <option key={c.text} value={c.value} >{c.text}</option>)
        }
      </select>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('app'))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Ill accept this as the answer when it allows me. Thanks once again!

Answer (score 1):

I guess you missing key={i}

```
  <select value={this.state.value} onChange={this.handleChange}>
    {
      this.bookOptions.map((c, i) => {
        <option key={i} value={c.value} >{c.text}</option>
      })
    }
  </select>
```

I just guess, not sure right or wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Edit, went a bit beyond scope.

You should set the data as props and add the options to an object to ensure map doesn't freak out when the props are empty.

```
class App extends Component {

  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {value: 'currentlyReading'};

    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
  }



    onHandleChange = (e) => {
        this.setState({
            state: e.target.value
        })
    };

  handleChange(e){
    this.setState({value: e.target.value});
  }
  render() {
    let oOptions = [];
    if( this.props.bookOptions ) {
        this.props.bookOptions.map((c) => {
            oOptions.push( <option key= {c.value} value={c.value} >{c.text}</option> );
        });
    }
    return (
      <select value={this.state.value} onChange={this.handleChange}>
        { oOptions }
      </select>
    );
  }
}

App.defaultProps = {
  bookOptions: [
  {
        value: 'currentlyReading',
        text: 'Currently Reading'
    },
    {
        value: 'wantToRead',
        text: 'Want to Read'
    },
    {
        value: 'read',
        text: 'Read'
    },
    {
        value: 'none',
        text: 'None'
    }]
};
```

You can either fetch the data from an endpoint at the top level  mount and pass them as **props**:

```
const resp = await fetch('/givemeprops', ...
const { data } = await resp.json();
<App bookOptions={data} />
```

Or you can put your ajax call inside any component's **componentDidMount** react.js lifecycle method and set them as **state**:

```
componentDidMount() {
  const resp = await fetch('/givemeprops', ...
  const { data } = await resp.json();
  this.setState({ bookOptions: data });
}
```

And use them from there.

```
let bookOptions = [{
        value: 'currentlyReading',
        text: 'Currently Reading'
    },
    {
        value: 'wantToRead',
        text: 'Want to Read'
    },
    {
        value: 'read',
        text: 'Read'
    },
    {
        value: 'none',
        text: 'None'
    }];
app.get('/givemeprops',
    res.json({ bookOptions: bookOptions })
);
```

There are other solutions for managing an app's props/state/interaction with the backend like Flux and Redux. I would recommend checking out graphql as well.

> Some great references:

[React Starter Kit](https://github.com/kriasoft/react-starter-kit/blob/master/src/routes/home/index.js)

[ComponentDidMount Example](https://daveceddia.com/ajax-requests-in-react/#ck_modal)